# JavaFX and property file encoding issue

Tags: java, javafx, encoding, localization

My application is written in JavaFX and is using property files saved in the JAR file (UTF-8 or ISO-8859_1 encoded). The files only contains ASCII characters.

There are cases when the user opens the application on computer with Chinese region and localization, and the interface is broken.

I checked the code, and the property files are loaded like this:

```
InputStream in = cls.getResourceAsStream("resources/" + cls.getSimpleName() + ".properties");
properties.load(new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

[image]

What could be wrong? Is it maybe a problem in JavaFX? Some strings are correct, like 'Sample Models' or the 'Connect' button.

Comment: Is it happening only for Chinese language ?

Comment: Yes, only for Chinese.

Comment: What's in properties file ? Can you share if possible and how does your localisations get loaded ?

Comment: There is nothing I do for internationalization. Only engish is supported. In the resource file I use something like: 
radioDB.text = Connect to the Database
radioDBDetail.text = ... and reverse engineer the schema from the database,\nexplore and query the data.
radioDB.tooltip = This is the common way to start a new project.<br>\
  This will reverse-engineer the schema from the database and create a new design model.<br>\
  You will be able to see the schema structure as diagrams, run queries, and explore the data.
radioDBDetail.cssClass= text-gray,font-large,text-center

Comment: This doesn’t look like being related to your property file at all. Just try to set UI elements with a plain string like `"Connect to the Database"` for testing.